# Button click not fire in javascript

Tags: javascript, button, click, server, ready

This is my code "btnviewreport1" is not fire after page load

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
        var hfDoYouWantPrint = document.getElementById('<%= hfDoYouWantPrint.ClientID %>').value;

        if (hfDoYouWantPrint == 1) {
            var r = confirm("Do you want to print?");
            if (r == true) {
                document.getElementById('<%= btnviewreport1.ClientID %>').click();
            } else {

            }
        }
    });


</script>
```

Comment: Please give your complete code

Answer (score 0):

you have to use Trigger instead of calling 'click()' method.

see below

```js
document.getElementById('').trigger('click');
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/